# Steps to figure out a posterior distribution when it might be simple enough to have an analytic form?

Tags: bayesian, posterior

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Steps to figure out a posterior distribution when it might be simple enough to have an analytic form?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23068/steps-to-figure-out-a-posterior-distribution-when-it-might-be-simple-enough-to-h)

I must admit this is an embarrassing question. I do a lot of programming for statistics work, but rarely do I ever deal with analytical formulas for things (it's usually all just based on algorithms for processing the data).

In this case, I am trying to compute a Bayesian estimate of some coefficients for an autoregression, with 11 data samples: $$ Y_{i} = \mu + \alpha\cdot{}Y_{i-1} + \epsilon_{i} $$
where $\epsilon_{i}$ is Gaussian with mean 0 and variance $\sigma_{e}^{2}$
The prior distribution on the vector $(\mu, \alpha)^{t}$ is Gaussian with mean $(0,0)$ and a diagonal covariance matrix with diagonal entries equal to $\sigma_{p}^{2}$.

Based on the autoregression formula, this means that the distribution of the data points (the $Y_{i}$) are normal with mean $\mu + \alpha\cdot{}Y_{i-1}$ and variance $\sigma_{e}^{2}$. Thus, the density for all of the data points $(Y)$ jointly (assuming independence, which is fine for the program I am writing), would be: $$ p(Y \quad | (\mu, \alpha)^{t}) = \prod_{i=2}^{11}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_{e}^{2}}}\exp{\frac{-(Y_{i} - \mu - \alpha\cdot{}Y_{i-1})^{2}}{2\sigma_{e}^{2}}}.$$

By Bayes' theorem, we can take the product of the above density with the prior density, and then we'll just need the normalizing constant. My hunch is that this should work out to be a Gaussian distribution, so we can worry about the normalizing constant at the end rather than explicitly calculating it with integrals over $\mu$ and $\alpha$.

This is the part I am having trouble with. How do I compute the multiplication of the prior density (which is multivariate) and this product of univariate data densities? The posterior needs to be purely a density of $\mu$ and $\alpha$, but I cannot see how you'll get that out of such a product.

Any pointers are really helpful, even if you just point me in the right direction and then I need to go and do the messy algebra (which is what I've already attempted several times).

As a starting point, here is the form of the numerator from Bayes' rule: $$ \frac{1}{(2\pi\sigma_{e}^{2})^{5}\cdot{}2\pi\sigma_{p}^{2}} \exp{\biggl [ \frac{1}{2\sigma_{e}^{2}}\sum_{i=2}^{11}(Y_{i} - \mu - \alpha\cdot{}Y_{i-1})^{2} - \frac{\mu^{2}}{2\sigma_{p}^{2}} - \frac{\alpha^{2}}{2\sigma_{p}^{2}} \biggr ] }.$$

The issue is how to see that this reduces down to a Gaussian density of $(\mu, \alpha)^{t}$.

Comment: EMS, I don't think it's an embarrassing question; judging from how you posed it, you've clearly put a significant amount of effort into thinking about your problem. Since this problem is about finding an analytical expression, it is out of scope here, and probably best asked on Stats.SE. I'm going to talk to their mods and see if it's a good migration candidate and get back to you; for the time being, please don't delete your question.

Comment: Great question, we're going to move it to stats so that the community there can see it.  Note: If you're a scicomp user and can answer this, you're welcome to register an account on the stats SE and answer the question there.