# Estimating a 1-D Brownian motion process using noisy observations

Tags: estimation, normal-distribution, gaussian-process

This question is a follow-up on my [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22852/bayesian-updating-using-n-noisy-observations-of-brownian-motion).

Suppose I have a Brownian motion process that is defined as follows: at time $i=1$ random variable $X_1\sim\mathbf{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, and, for any subsequent random variables $X_i$ and $X_j$ such that $i<j$, $X_j-X_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0,(j-i)\sigma^2)$.

I collect $n$ noisy observations $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ of $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$, where $Y_i\sim\mathcal{N}(X_i,N_0)$.  I would like to construct $\{\hat{X}_i\}_{i=1}^n$ such that the squared error $\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\hat{X}_i)^2$ is minimized.  Unlike in my [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22852/bayesian-updating-using-n-noisy-observations-of-brownian-motion), the causality is not a constraint here (I have access to all $n$ observations and am interested in the "evolution" of the Brownian motion random process over the entire window of observation.)  I am wondering if it is possible to obtain closed-form expressions for $\{\hat{X}_i\}_{i=1}^n$ from $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ as well as the squared error $\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\hat{X}_i)^2$ given $\sigma^2$, $N_0$, and $n$.

Note that this problem is easily convertable into the continuous domain, which, as I have been told, admits solutions using [Wiener filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_filter).  Since my problem (converted to that domain) requires a non-causal filter, the Wiener filter seems very simple.  However, use of the Wiener filter requires that the signal is stationary and, in my case, Brownian motion is not stationary, as one can readily compute:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}E[X_iX_j]&=&\int\int x_i x_j p(x_i)p(x_j|x_i)dx_jdx_i\\
&=&\int\int x_i x_j \phi(x_i;\mu,i\sigma^2)\phi(x_j;x_i,(j-i)\sigma^2)dx_jdx_i\\
&=&\int x_i^2\phi(x_i;\mu,i\sigma^2)dx_i\\
&=&i\sigma^2
\end{array}$$
showing that autocorrelation actually depends on $i$ as opposed to $j-i$ (where $\phi(x;\mu,\sigma^2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ is the pdf of the Gaussian distribution).

Does anyone know where to go from here?  Are there closed-form expressions for $\{\hat{X}_i\}_{i=1}^n$ from $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ as well as the squared error $\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\hat{X}_i)^2$ given $\sigma^2$, $N_0$, and $n$? This seems to me like a problem that someone thought about before.  Unfortunately, I am not well-versed in filtering/signal-processing -- perhaps there is a version of a Wiener filter that could work.  I would appreciate any guidance in figuring this out.

**EDIT**: This may be soluble using the first principles from which the Wiener filter is derived, i.e. via the orthogonality principle and using the expectation operator as a dot-product.  I'm fearful that this might get me stuck with a nasty integral equation, requiring the use of transforms (which I am not too familiar with to begin with) but I'll try it in the morning.